# array_ push gets executed just once

Tags: php

I have created dynmically checkboxes  like below

```
$extList = array(
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "com"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "com.tr"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "tv"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "net"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "gen.tr"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "de"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "org"),

);


foreach ($extList as $key => $value) {
    ?>
    <span> <input type="checkbox" name="ext[]"
                  value="<?= $value["extName"] ?>"> <?= $value["extName"]
```

What I want to do is to add theese values into an array I have tried something like this But I think  I missed out something Because It just show a single record

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["ext"]); $i++) {
        $list = array(
            "extName" => $_POST["ext"][$i],
            "server" => $extList[$i]["server"]

    );
        array_push($extAndServer, $list);
   }
```

Comment: Make sure your input fields are named `ext[]` and not `ext`.

Comment: its working on my side..

Comment: i choose `com, com.tr` from checkbox and getting this result `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [extName] => com
            [server] => whois.verisign-grs.net
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [extName] => com.tr
            [server] => whois.verisign-grs.net
        ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need declare your array before using [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) as like:

```
$extAndServer = array(); // declare your array
```

I tried this example:

**Your Array:**

```
<?php
$extList = array(
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "com"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "com.tr"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "tv"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "net"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "gen.tr"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "de"),
array("server" => "whois.verisign-grs.net", "extName" => "org"),
);
?>
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post">
<?php
foreach ($extList as $key => $value) {
    ?>
    <span> <input type="checkbox" name="ext[]"
                  value="<?= $value["extName"] ?>"> <?= $value["extName"] ?>
    <?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Result:**

```
<?php
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $extAndServer = array(); // this line will solve your problem
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["ext"]); $i++) {
        $list = array(
            "extName" => $_POST["ext"][$i],
            "server" => $extList[$i]["server"]
        );
        array_push($extAndServer, $list);
    }
    print_r($extAndServer);
}
?>
```